# Eclipse / Tour de Flex plugin / Problem when accessing Tour de Flex view

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, adobe

Eclipse world is totally new to me.
I've just installed Tour de Flex plugin in my Eclipse / Flex environment

(Eclipse Platform Version: 3.3.3.r33).

Everything went well.
Now if I try to view tour de Flex here's what I do :
- Menu Windows => Other views
- A popup box opens, I choose "Tour de Flex",

Then it asks me : "Please locate the Tour de Flex application on your system".

Where should I look ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the page does not explain is that the AIR version is a prerequisite for the Eclipse plug-in.

1. Download Adobe AIR if necessary
2. Install the Tour de Flex application from the home page.
3. Locate the "Tour de Flex" exe.  (e.g. - C:\Program Files\TourDeFlex\TourDeFlex.exe)

That should get it to work.